# Linq orderby, can't work out how to use it

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sql-order-by

I have this function:

```
/// <summary>
/// Return array of all badges for a users
/// </summary>
public static Badge[] getUserBadges(int UserID)
{
    Badge[] ReturnBadges;

    using (MainContext db = new MainContext())
    {
        var q = db.tblBadgeUsers
        .Where(c => c.UserID == UserID)
        .GroupBy(c => c.BadgeID)
        .Select(c => new { BadgeCount = c.Count(), TheBadge = c });

        ReturnBadges = new Badge[q.Count()];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var UserBadge in q)
        {
            ReturnBadges[i] = new Badge(UserBadge.TheBadge.Key);
            ReturnBadges[i].Quantity = UserBadge.BadgeCount;
            i++;
        }
    }

    return ReturnBadges;
}
```

I wish to order by `tblBadges.OrderID ascending` but I can't seem to find out where to put it, can anyone help?

I've tried:

```
.OrderBy(c=> c.TheBadge.OrderID)
```

But it's not valid code.  `TheBadge.Key` in the loop is a `tblBadges` type.  It's confusing me a bit why intellisense wont let me do the order by anywhere!

Comment: Where did you have the `Orderby` statement?

Comment: "But it's not valid code." On what line did you try adding the OrderBy and what specifically was the error message?

Comment: Should that be `.OrderBy(c=> c.OrderID)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TheBadge` isn't a *single* badge, it's a *group* of badges... so I'd personally rename it if I were you. Now, *which* `OrderId` do you want to get? You've got multiple entities in the gruop. For example, you could do this:

```
var q = db.tblBadgeUsers
    .Where(c => c.UserID == UserID)
    .GroupBy(c => c.BadgeID)
    .Select(c => new { BadgeCount = c.Count(), TheBadge = c })
    .OrderBy(x => x.TheBadge.First().OrderId);
```

That will order by some notional "first" element - although I don't know what the generated SQL will look like.

If you expect the `OrderId` to be the same for every badge with the same ID, you might use:

```
var q = db.tblBadgeUsers
    .Where(c => c.UserID == UserID)
    .GroupBy(c => new { c.BadgeID, c.OrderID })
    .OrderBy(group => group.Key.OrderID)
    .Select(c => new { BadgeCount = c.Count(), TheBadge = c });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var q = db.tblBadgeUsers
    .Where(c => c.UserID == UserID)
    .GroupBy(c => c.BadgeID)
    .Select(c => new { BadgeCount = c.Count(), TheBadge = c.Key }) // *mod
    .OrderBy(c=> c.TheBadge.OrderID);      // * added
```

In the following line, TheBadge is a linq collection, not the badge itself.  You want `c.Key`.

```
    .Select(c => new { BadgeCount = c.Count(), TheBadge = c })
```